# Port forward linux iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

My current network setup consists of a physical nic eth1 receiving my public ip from the modem. Next I have kvm/qemu virtual machines running on a virtual network using the ip range `192.168.122.0 - 200` witch is the default NAT network created by kvm. My issue is that I have a virtual server running my OpenVPN server that needs to be accessible outside the LAN. The VPN server has a static ip of `192.168.122.4`. I would like to port forward ports `943,1194` to my vpn server, how would i do this in the linux iptables?

NOTE: the following rules were added to the iptables by kvm:
I also have other rules for filtering but I don't think those are necessary to show.

```
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -p udp -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.93/32 -j SNAT --to-source (my public ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick, it will take all traffic on you public interface coming in for the VPN ports and change the destination to your VPN machine.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 943, 1194 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.4
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 943, 1194 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.4
```

This asummes you don't have any rules filtering your forward. If you do the following line will allow all traffic from the outside to your VPN machine.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -d 192.168.122.4 -j ACCEPT
```